# Divide Every Other Line Between Two Files

Tags: python, bash, division

I am currently trying to automate a process that alarms me if we see a sudden change in amount of VMs running month over month. Here is what the data looks like

```
January.txt               February.txt

Web Fleet                 Web Fleet
100                       112
Proxy Fleet               Proxy Fleet
25                        22
Beta Fleet                Beta Fleet
12                        10
```

I basically want to open the two different files, and have python divide each line with numbers between the two files. From there, I can say "if <= 1 then alarm" kind of thing. But I cant seem to figure out how to tell it to do every other line between two different files. Normally I would do this in bash but I am trying to keep the entire process in a currently running python script that currently generates the files and performs some other tasks to get this data.

Here is a sample of a way I got it sort of working with bash

```
paste January.txt feburary.txt | awk 'NR%2==0' | awk '{ print $1 / $2 }'
```

EDIT: The data is always in the same order, Web Fleet always at the top, Proxy Fleet always Second, so on and so on.

Comment: Do the lines of your files always match up, or do you have to have your code make them match? If they're already matched, I suspect `zip` will do most what you want pretty much out of the box.

Comment: They always match up. the Python script performs a query 1 at a time in a set order to ensure that.

Comment: FYI Your sample code could be written as: `paste January.txt feburary.txt | awk 'NR%2==0 { print $1 / $2 }'` Or `awk 'NR == FNR {a[NR] = $0;next}FNR%2 == 0{print a[FNR]/$1}' jan.txt feb.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code -

```
with open('January.txt', 'r') as f1, open('February.txt', 'r') as f2:
    for x, y in zip(f1.read().splitlines()[1::2], f2.read().splitlines()[1::2]):
        print(float(x) / int(y))
```

Output -

```
0.8928571428571429
1.1363636363636365
1.2
```

Comment: if he's working with python 2.7 he needs a float division, otherwise he will get an int answer...

Comment: @pekapa edited it. now it works with both Python 2 & 3.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably simpler to read the contents of both files upfront, `zip` them together, then iterate moving 2 lines at a time:

```
with open("jan.txt") as file1:
    with open("feb.txt") as file2:
        lines = zip(file1.readlines(), file2.readlines())
        for line1, line2 in lines[1::2]:
            val1 = float(line1.strip())
            val2 = float(line2.strip())
            print val1/val2
```

The `[1::2]` bit means to start from index 1, and move 2 items at a time

An alternative implementation that doesn't read the file contents upfront:

```
with open("jan.txt") as file1:
    with open("feb.txt") as file2:
        while True:
            file1.readline()
            file2.readline()
            line1 = file1.readline()
            line2 = file2.readline()
            if line1 == "" or line2 == "":
                break

            val1 = float(line1.strip())
            val2 = float(line2.strip())
            print val1/val2
```